# Autonumbering a specific column in a quick part in Word 2013

Tags: ms-word, word-2013

I have created a Word 2013 template that we use as a protocol-template at work. Every protocol entry comes from a quick part that contains a table. In this table, I have a field called `Entry-No` that I would like to be `auto-numbered` each time I insert a new entry quick part.

Does anyone know how to do this or if this is even possible? I Googled around but found only stuff that is more general than what I need.

EDIT: BTW, I can't use macros, my supervisor won't let me use them for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have, so far, found a workaround. I replaced my Rich Text Content Control, which I originally used, with simple numbering. I formatted the numbering, removing indent, changing font, etc. so it looks consistent and now, whenever I insert a new quick part, in the same cell in which I placed the numbering, I now get a new, incremented value.